# Android, setOnClickLister Error, I don't see what's wrong

Tags: android, android-fragments, onclicklistener, android-scrollview

I keep getting the following error:

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ScrollView.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference
```

When button is clicked, I want scrollView and it's contents to hide.

But I don't see what's wrong. I connected my button to scrollView but it doesn't work. Here's my code for button in fragment:

```
 public class SavedBroad extends Fragment {

Button activityButtonPhoto;
public ScrollView broadScroll;


Button activityButtonBroad;
public ScrollView photoScroll;

View rootView;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_saved_broad_tabbar, container, false);


     broadScroll = rootView.findViewById(R.id.BroadScrollView); 
   // photoScroll = rootView.findViewById(R.id.PhotoScrollView);  


  //  broadScroll= getActivity().findViewById(R.id.BroadScrollView); 
  // photoScroll=getActivity().findViewById(R.id.PhotoScrollView);




    activityButtonPhoto= rootView.findViewById(R.id.PhotoVid);
    activityButtonPhoto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {


            broadScroll.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        }

    });

    return rootView;

    }


   }
```

Here's my XML file:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/PhotoVid"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
    android:text="PhotoVid"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.155"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button

    android:id="@+id/broad"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
    android:text="Broadcast"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.741"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/BroadScrollView"
    android:layout_width="393dp"
    android:layout_height="505dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="144dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/broad"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/BroadLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" />
</ScrollView>

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/PhotoScrollView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="433dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/BroadScrollView"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/broad"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/PhotoVidLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" />
</ScrollView>
```

I don't understand why the button to hide ScrollView is giving me issue.

Comment: Are you sure `activity_saved_broad_tabbar` is the right layout for that `Fragment`? Also, you probably don't want to find those first two `View`s in the `Activity`.

Comment: Can you share xml code what you have used to identify clearly?

Answer (score 0):

Here you are trying to get the button:

```
activityButtonPhoto= rootView.findViewById(R.id.PhotoVid);
```

If you check after this line, `activityButtonPhoto` is `null`, meaning the button wasn't found with the id `PhotoVid` in the layout `activity_saved_broad_tabbar` which was inflated into `rootView`.

As it is null, when you try to set the `OnClickListener` it throws the null pointer exception.

Check the id is correctly spelled and the the layout contains this id.

Comment: I changed nothing and now the button click works but now ScrollView has the same error. But I included my XML file.

Comment: The error you show now is different from the one you originally posted.

Answer (score 0):

It's a spelling mistake.

In your layout xml, your ScrollView is `android:id="@+id/BroadScrollView"` but you are using `R.id.BroadcastScrollView`

So Android cannot find this ScrollView in your rootView, so `broadScroll` will be `null` and that caused NullPointerException.

Comment: Update: Since you have editted your question, your problem will be gone, please don't keep changing your question like that!

Comment: No, the problem still persists.

Comment: No, both the Id's match. So it's not the issue.

Comment: @iBEK I had posted my answer before you edited your question. At this time the ids is not correct!!! Ok I will look at it again

Answer (score 0):

Hi can you try this.

```
public class SavedBroad extends Fragment 
{

  Button activityButtonPhoto;
  public ScrollView broadScroll;


  Button activityButtonBroad;
  public ScrollView photoScroll;


  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  }

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) 
  {
       View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_saved_broad_tabbar, container, false);


       broadScroll = rootView.findViewById(R.id.BroadScrollView); 
     // photoScroll = rootView.findViewById(R.id.PhotoScrollView);  


    //  broadScroll= getActivity().findViewById(R.id.BroadScrollView); 
    // photoScroll=getActivity().findViewById(R.id.PhotoScrollView);




      activityButtonPhoto= rootView.findViewById(R.id.PhotoVid);
      activityButtonPhoto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View view) {

              //broadScroll.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              broadScroll.setVisibility(View.GONE);

          }

      });

      return rootView;

  }


}
```